# Can't see organization in "Select from" list even have "Organization Administrator" permission in the organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a G-suit account "admin@myorg.com"

I logged in google console with admin@myorg.com and created a project "myproject" in organization "myorg.com".

There are another G-suit account "security@otherorg.com" in group "secgroup@otherorg.com"

I give "secgroup@otherorg.com" two roles, "Organization Administrator" and "Security Admin" in (myorg.com) organization level

But security@otherorg.com can't see "myproject" in "myorg.com", he see "myproject" in "No organization".

How to let security@otherorg.com see "myproject" in "myorg.com"?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Viewing all projects in an organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-resource-management?hl=en#viewing_all_projects_in_an_organization): "The _No organization*_ option in the _Organization_ drop-down lists the following projects:
**-** Projects that do not belong to the Organization yet. **-** Projects for which the user has access to, but are under an Organization to which the user does not have access."

Comment: I"ve tried on my organization and granted roles `Organization Administrator`  and `Security Admin` to `username@gmail.com`. After that I was able to see all the projects in my organization under `username@gmail.com`. Do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The project and organization is correct without any change.

Maybe it need time to let GCP update organization list and link project to the organization.

Thank you Serhii Rohoza.

Comment: Do you still have an issue? If yes, please contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) or file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: @B Kevin, do you find a solution ? I'm facing the exactly same issue right now.